# There is some attempt to build a magnetic flywheel (reservoir of motion)

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, magnetic-fields, electrical-engineering

We know how [flywheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flywheel) works! There is some attempt to substitute the flywheel-friction mechanism for some magnetic torque ?

Exist some mechanism that uses thermal cycle of gases for generate magnetic fields?

Answer (score 2):

They do make such flywheels. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flywheel): "Some modern flywheels are made of carbon fiber materials and employ magnetic bearings, enabling them to revolve at speeds up to 60,000 RPM."

Comment: Can we use magnetic field for substitue the friction in the flywheel with the engineerings ?

Comment: You mean magnetically levitate it? Those exist. [From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flywheel): "Some modern flywheels are made of carbon fiber materials and employ magnetic bearings, enabling them to revolve at speeds up to 60,000 RPM."